# Trigger captures data and moves it to another table with different columns

Tags: sql, xampp

I need to create a trigger that captures the data of certain columns of a table and then the data appears in another table, but in columns with different names.
They are two different tables with columns of different names.

Comment: Ok, then in the trigger handling (though you don't say what type of trigger), simply insert the values to the other table to the respective columns.

Comment: But I don't know what the code to put is like.
Do you have an example?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.